# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate functions not called for container view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, transition

I'm adding a View Controller's view to a container view programmatically and want it to have an animated transition but the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` functions aren't called, even if I call `beginAppearanceTransition(animated:)`.

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
self.secondViewController = secondViewController
secondViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
containerView.addConstraints(secondViewController.view.pinnedConstraints(view: containerView))
secondViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
secondViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
secondViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
```

When executing the code above, `animationController(forPresented:presenting:source:) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` is never called in the current view controller